# How can I create a new instance of a class on the drop event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm making a logic gate emulator, and I'm trying to make a drag and drop menu, and when I drop it I want to create a new instance of the class (gate) that the div is from, with all of the same functions. my current code is:

```html
    
    typeOfGates = [new and_gate(20,10),new or_gate(20,80),new or3_gate(20,150),new not_gate(20,220),new       xor_gate(20,290),new nor_gate(20,360),new nor3_gate(20,430),new nand_gate(20,500),new nand3_gate(20,570),]
    
    for(i = 0; i < typeOfGates.length; i++){
        typeOfGates[i].show();
        $(typeOfGates[i].div).draggable({
            helper:'clone',
            cursor: 'move',
            stop: function(e,ui){
                //i want to create a new class here, for example, new and_gate(10,10), the same as whatever class is being cloned
            }
       });
    }
```

The current code is being ran [here](http://ryangrube.com/projects/LogicGates/index.html) if you want to see.  (sorry if the question is bad, I really have no clue how to phrase this)

Answer (score -1):

```html
    
    typeOfGates = [new and_gate(20,10),new or_gate(20,80),new or3_gate(20,150),new not_gate(20,220),new       xor_gate(20,290),new nor_gate(20,360),new nor3_gate(20,430),new nand_gate(20,500),new nand3_gate(20,570),]
    
    for(i = 0; i < typeOfGates.length; i++){
        typeOfGates[i].show();
        $(typeOfGates[i].div).draggable({
            helper:'clone',
            cursor: 'move',
            stop: function(e,ui){
                //i want to create a new class here, for example, new and_gate(10,10), the same as whatever class is being cloned
            }
       });
    }
```

Comment: Jansen, please take the [tour]. We're not a social media site, so chatty comments aren't appropriate. Welcome.

Comment: This answer would be better if you offered some explanation (in the answer) of your changes. Near as I can tell there are none.